# Whats the addrlen field in recvfrom() used for?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, recv

I'm using recvfrom in my program to get DGRAM data from a server I specify in src_addr.  However, I'm not sure why I need to initialize and pass in addrlen.

I read the man page and I didn't really understand what it's getting at.

> If  src_addr  is  not NULL, and the underlying protocol provides the source address, this source address is filled in.  When
>   src_addr is NULL, nothing is filled in; in this case, addrlen is not
>   used, and should also be NULL.  The argument addrlen is a value-result argument, which the caller should initialize before the
>   call to the size of the buffer  associated  with  src_addr,  and 
>   modified  on return  to  indicate the actual size of the source address.  The returned address is truncated if the buffer provided is too small;
>   in this case, addrlen will return a value greater than was supplied to the call.

I'm guessing that it's got something to do with src_addr being ipv4 or ipv6.  Is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it does have to do with IPv4 vs. IPv6 and the different amounts of storage required for each.

Comment: When receiving your DGRAM, the source address, if provided by the protocol within the packet, will will copied into the buffer you supply with the src_addr parameter. You set the length value to the maximum size the buffer passed as src_addr can accept. The results, if all goes well, will be the source address populated into your buffer and the "used" byte count updated in the addr_len variable you passed by address. In effect, you're saying "Here's a buffer and its size. please fill it with the source address if you can. If it can, it does so, and updates the size to reflect the actual count.

Comment: Lots of different kind of network protocols existed before IP took over the world.  Things like DECnet, IPX, AppleTalk, NetBIOS, Banyan.  Each with their own idea of what an address looks like.  And yes, ip4 vs ip6 today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe there is a missinterpretation from your side. Talking about:

```
ssize_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags, 
                 struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

`src_addr` is **not** used to hand *in* the adress that you would like to listen to, but rather a storage location provided by you to get the actual source address handed *out*.

Thus if you set `src_addr` to NULL because youre not interested in the address at all, you don't have to care about `addrlen` as it won't get used anyway.

If on the other hand you want to be informed about the source address, you not only have to provide a storage location, but also tell how big the storage location you provided is.
Thats why you should initialize `*addr_len` to the buffer size you allocated.

After your call the value pointed to by `addrlen` will inform you about how much (if any) of the space you allocated to store the source address got actually filled with data.

### About sizes

The whole hassle with struct sockaddr and passing sizes back and forth has to do with the fact that even thoug they're most heavily used in networking sockets were intended to be much more general concept.

Think about unix domain sockets as an an example as they are implemented via the filesystem they require an adressing scheme totaly different from that known from IP based networking. The type of sockaddr used here is:

```
struct sockaddr_un {
  sa_family_t sun_family;               /* AF_UNIX */
  sun_path[UNIX_PATH_MAX];  /* pathname */
};
```

Compare this to the struct used in IP based networking:

```
struct sockaddr_in {
  sa_family_t    sin_family; /* address family: AF_INET */
  in_port_t      sin_port;   /* port in network byte order */
  struct in_addr sin_addr;   /* internet address */
};
```

it should be clear both don't have too much in common.

sockets were designed to be able to fit both cases.

Comment: This was it.  For some reason I thought you were supposed to populate src_addr before passing it in.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if we use `NULL` in `sendto` as the `destaddr`

Answer (score 3):

```
ssize_t recvfrom(int socket, void *buffer, size_t length, int flags,
         struct sockaddr *address, socklen_t *address_len);`
```

The `address_len` argument specifies the length of the `address` structure i.e. the number of bytes to use from the start address indicated at `address`(start address of memory location + number of bytes from the start address that hold the value)

The structure is defined in `/usr/include/bits/socket.h`

```
/* Structure describing a generic socket address.  */
struct sockaddr
{
    __SOCKADDR_COMMON (sa_);    /* Common data: address family and length.      */  
    char sa_data[14];       /* Address data.  */
};
```

Thus the `sa_data` field holds the address data (start address of the data) whose length is indicated by the `address_len` argument.

> ... whenever a function says it takes a struct sockaddr* you can cast your
>   struct sockaddr_in*, struct sockaddr_in6*, or struct sockadd_storage*
>   to that type with ease and safety.

Therefore, as indicated in the man page and @WhozCraig in the comment to your question, this field is updated with the actual size when the method returns.

**More information**

- [recvfrom](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/recvfrom.html)
- [Beej's Guide to Network Programming - struct sockaddr and pals](http://www.retran.com/beej/sockaddr_inman.html)

Comment: This is only partly correct as struct sockaddr is just some kind of master-template - there wouldn't be any sense in having to pass the size along as the function hopefully could be implemented cleverly enough to get `sizeof (struct sockaddr)` on its own. In fact theres a whole bunch of different struct sockaddr structures. Which one is used effectively depends on the underlying protocol being used.