# Why do we need Value-Result arguments in socket programming? (Clarification required)

Tags: c++, c, sockets, parameter-passing

I am a little confused when asked a question such as "What is a Value-Result argument and WHY is it needed in Socket Programming?"

I am struggling to fully understand what exactly a value result argument is, despite reading countless pages and other questions on here.

My understanding is that in a value result argument the kernel is able to make changes to the argument passed(because we give a reference/pointer to it, not just its value) and return it to the the process/function that called it. It is both a "value" when the function is called(tells kernel the size of struct so it doesn't write too much for example) and a result when the function returns(how much we actually wrote in the struct).

What I am struggling to answer, is why this is so important in Socket Programming? In particular, when we are dealing with `sockaddr` Structs and passing their reference AND size over, i.e. `accept()`

I realize this question may sound somewhat silly, but any clarification on this would be great, so thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is a little strange - I fail to see why such arguments would be *needed* - and "socket programming" is a pretty broad term. Have you considered asking the person who asks you these questions what they mean?

Comment: Alas they are unavailable currently. The method accept() for example is value result, i should add that in.

Comment: I have found another thread that should answer your question. Can someone please close as duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168095/whats-the-addrlen-field-in-recvfrom-used-for

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have the correct understanding of *what* a value-result parameter is.  You assign an input value to a variable and pass it by-reference so the function can modify the variable with an output value.  This saves having to pass a separate parameter for the output, or change the semantics of the function's return value.

The *reason* this is needed for `sockaddr` parameters is because different transports implement different `sockaddr_...` structures, which have different sizes and layouts (`sockaddr_in` for IPv4, `sockaddr_in6` for IPv6, `sockaddr_un` for UNIX domain sockets, etc). Most platforms also provide an implementation of the `sockaddr_storage` structure, which is large enough to hold all other `sockaddr_...` structs, and is useful when writing multi-transport code.

So, in the case of `accept()`, you have to pass in the FULL size of the buffer that will receive the client's `sockaddr_...`.  When a new client arrives, `accept()` will validate that the buffer is large enough to receive the client's actual `sockaddr_...` data before then populating the buffer, and will return how much of the buffer was actually filled in.

For example, if you know the socket only supports IPv4 (was created as an `AF_INET`-family socket), then you can use a `sockaddr_in` as the buffer and `sizeof(sockaddr_in)` as the buffer size, or you can use a `sockaddr_storage` as the buffer and `sizeof(sockaddr_storage)` as the buffer size.  In either case, `accept()` will populate the buffer with a `sockaddr_in` and return the buffer size as `sizeof(sockaddr_in)`.  Same with an IPv6-only socket (created as an `AF_INET6`-family socket), just with `sockaddr_in6` instead.

Now, lets say you have a dual-stack socket that supports both IPv4 and IPv6 (an `AF_INET6`-family socket with the `IPV6_V6ONLY` option disabled).  You can use a `sockaddr_storage` as the buffer and `sizeof(sockaddr_storage)` as the buffer size, and `accept()` will populate the buffer with either a `sockaddr_in` or `sockaddr_in6` and return an appropriate buffer size, depending on whether an IPv4 or IPv6 client was accepted.  You can then read the `ss_family` field of the `sockaddr_storage` and type-cast the data to either `sockaddr_in` for `AF_INET` or `sockaddr_in6` for `AF_INET6`.

Comment: Thank you very much that makes alot more sense! Especially with regards to supporting both IPv4 and V6 when the buffer is populated with the appropiate protocol struct. Many thanks :)